SSIS Consolidate multiple tables to one
I have a data source with a database containing 5987 tables (a lot of these are empty - maybe 50-60%), and it gets data from Microsoft Dynamics and fills a server that I don't want/can't modify. So I'm extracting the data to my own server, where I want to index it.
My end goal is to create a tabular model. However, I can't find an efficient way to build DimTables and FactTables when they need data from multiple tables. My best guess is to create a raw data table consisting of all of the tables for staging and then do my ETL:
Data source -> Staging -> ETL -> Dim+FactTables (SSIS) -> SSAS

Is this advised or is there a better way?
I know, I can use SSMS to export the database, but I cant figure out how to join the tables. Maybe I need to do it in two steps, but it seems wrong/redundant.
Help and input are much appreciated!
